# Convergent decreasing exponential product

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was curious and wondered if a number infinitely, iteratively multiplied by a scalar that approached 1, would it converge on some value. In a simulation, it seems to.

```
def number(itrs):
  total = 1
  for i in range(itrs):
    scalar = (1 + 1/10**i)
    total *= scalar 
  return total
```

Where number(10), number(100) and number(1000) converge on 2.2244691382741024. I believe that it's irrational; this is just what can be stored in memory.

This number looks vaguely familiar- is it some famous number that's been used in some branches of mathematics?

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{10^i}\right) $$

Comment: I am confused, what is exactly your recursion? Can you write it in MathJax?

Comment: It's actually just iteration, not recursion. My mistake!

Comment: You can express it as a ratio of two  values of the [Euler function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P_n= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{10^i}\right)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (10^i+1) }{\prod_{i=1}^{n} 10^i}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (10^i+1) }{10^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}}$$

The successive numerators are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \prod_{i=1}^{n} (10^i+1) \\
 1 & 11 \\
 2 & 1111 \\
 3 & 1112111 \\
 4 & 11122222111 \\
 5 & 1112233333322111 \\
 6 & 1112234445555444322111 \\
 7 & 11122345567788888776554322111 \\
 8 & 1112234567901234445444320987654322111 \\
 9 & 1112234569013469013345555433098643098654322111 \\
10 & 11122345691246924702469023344331986419641864208654322111   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you see some patterns

If you use the q-Pochhammer symbols
$$P_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(-1;\frac{1}{10}\right)_{n+1}\quad \implies \quad P_\infty=\frac 12 \left(-1;\frac{1}{10}\right)_{\infty }$$
$$P_\infty=1.1122345691370506321260780670944058037475074675776\cdots$$ does not correspond to any specific constant (at least to me).

What is interesting is to write the number in binary form
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \prod_{i=1}^{n} (10^i+1)\qquad \text{in binary} \\
 1 & 1011_2 \\
 2 & 10001010111_2 \\
 3 & 100001111100000101111_2 \\
 4 & 1010010110111011111010010000011111_2 \\
 5 & 11111100111001001000000000101111010111000101111111_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Surprizingly of not, this number is "close" to
$$\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{11}{24}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)$$ in an error of $4.69\times 10^{-9}$.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Very informative